# Inversion points- its geometric meaning.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I just recently learnt the definition of inverse of a point with respect to a circle.
It says:
Two points P and Q are said to be inverse points with respect to a circle with centre O and radius r if Q lies on the ray OP and OP.OQ=$r^2$.
Is there any geometric interpretation to this definition (for  my better understanding)?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider your plane to be the stereographic projection of the sphere, then inversion in the circle is the projection of reflection through the equator of the sphere. The center of your circle comes from the north pole, and the point at infinity on the plane comes from the south pole.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! But I want to know it for a general plane not necessarily a stereographic projection...

Comment: Well if you insist on remaining in the plane, all we can say is what it does to points on the plane. But you've already said it yourself. It moves points outside the circle to inside, and vice versa. Thinking of the plane including its point at infinite as a sphere (the Riemann sphere) is often considered a useful point of view.

Comment: I agree with @ziggurism : one of the best way to understand the interest of this 2D transform is to use 3D (just like 2D projective geometry is well understood using 3D "glasses").